# How can i manage session replication in weblogic clustering

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing

I have developed an application and want to deploy it on a cluster environment.But I am not sure how replicate session when one server goes down.

What are the things I need to do for session replication?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of front end do you have? Is your weblogic being served by an apache?

Comment: We are using Weblogic proxy (HttpClusterServlet) as a front end.I am able to manage session in multiple servers through Hazelcast web filter.BUt sometimes i m getting session id as null and sometimes i have been logged out from the application saying "please login".

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](http://hazelcast.com/use-cases/web-session-clustering/)

It is always better to have session replication off of weblogic and on the web tier end as the target is weblogic.

You can also look into session persistence and how it can be achieved is hazelcast.

I'm sure a proper cluster with caching such as coherence can maintain sessions over multiple machines and provide high availability in weblogic. From an infrastructure stand point, I would go with Coherence or "Coherence-like" products to achieve session replication and persistence.

Comment: HI The Curious traveller,I am using Hazelcast 3.3.2.but still getting same issue.could you please help me step-by-step procedure to implement hazelcast

Comment: HI ia heve used hazelcast-3.3.2,hazelcast-wm-3.3.2,added in lib folder,added filter in web.xml .But sometimes i am getting session id as null but not everytime.please suggest iif i miss anything

Comment: I have not worked with hazelcast before so I can just speculate. I apologize for that. The only other thing i can think of is checking the hazelcast logs and seeing if it was called upon.

Comment: Using some third-party clustering system in WebLogic is a bad idea, when WebLogic has very good clustering built in already.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic has built-in clustering, so you don't need some other thing to do this. Also, WebLogic Suite includes Coherence, and with WebLogic Suite you can turn on Coherence session clustering just by clicking a check-box in the console.

Please read [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12-ManageSessions--4478/session.htm)